# CSS Display - Div text is wrapped

Tags: html, css

If you go [here](http://www.venue3405.com/) you will see at the very bottom a light gray box that says "Partners". While the site is in full screen mode everything looks correct but when you edit your browser and make the width smaller then it switches to have an image on each line. It appears to happen when the max-width of the DIV gets below 1000px which you can see from the below I have the CSS set to be a max-width of 1000px or 95% of the browser width. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

```
.footer-full-row {
padding-left: 20px;
width: 95%;
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
color: #fff;
background:gray;
}
```

Comment: Your images are set wide in style\

Comment: Your responsive.css styles are kicking in at 1020px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your responsive.css file, you have media queries that set all `img` elements to `display: block;`.  You could override that using something like

```
.footer-widget img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Adding your code into the responsive.css file fixed the issue. Thank you

Comment: .footer-full-row img {
      display: inline-block;
  }

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want the images to not display in a separate row each, so you need to add this css property to .textwidget img :

```
.textwidget img{
display:inline-block;
}
```

This will make it wrap anyway,in order to leave the size of the images as is, but you'll not get each picture in a separate ligne, it'll be wrapping according to the need of the page.

Answer (score 0):

In your *style.css* change:

```
#footer .textwidget {
    background: none;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

to this:

```
#footer .textwidget {
    background: none;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
 }
```

Comment: Adding "display: flex;" didnt fix the issue. You can see the layout at http://www.venue3405.com/_temp_display_flex.gif after making the change. It makes all the images overlap. It should fit the images into the size of the box and wrap according to the size.